An interpretation for Propagator $D(x-y)$
When I learn QFT I always see that when we consider the causality problem in QFT, at first we may try to compute the propagator $D(x-y)$ for spacelike distance $(x-y)^2<0$, which is nonzero. An explaination is that, we explain $D(x-y)$ as the quantum amplitude for a particle to travel from $y\to x$, and $D(y-x)$ as the amplitude for $x\to y$. But still I have a question: How we explain that $D(x-y)\ne 0$ consist with causality? My idea is: When we create a particle at spacepoint $x$ and measure it at spacepoint $y$, we have the probability $D(x-y)$. But at the same time, there is a probability $D(y-x)$ that a same particle leaves spacepoint $y$. So altogether, the "really" probablity to find the particle propagate from $x$ to $y$ is $D(x-y)-D(y-x)=0$, which consistent with causality.
Is my interpretation right?

See my answer here
